# Navigating in the python terminal

Tags: python, shell, navigation

I want a 64-bit python interpreter on my Mac so I had to rebuild from source. However, with my own custom build interpreter I run into issues when I try to navigate when I run the interpreter from inside a shell. Typing python into the bash shell results in the familiar:

```
Python 2.6.3 (r263:75183, Oct 23 2009, 14:23:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However, when I try to navigate with left-arrow and right-arrow, I get weird characters:

```
Python 2.6.3 (r263:75183, Oct 23 2009, 14:23:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[D^[[C^[[C^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C
```

This does not occur in Apple's default interpreter.

What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like your custom build didn't include readline.  Should be a simple config change and rebuild, check [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/30809-linux-python-arrow-key-problem-when-interactive-interpreter) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. 
Apparently Appled does not include the GNU readline utility by default. It can be downloaded and installed from 
http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 0):

Installing the GNU readline library from [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), and rebuilding python fixes the problem.